# How to call JButton from other class java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a GUI class which contains a JButton:

```
public class GUI {

   static JFrame mainFrame;
   static JLabel headerLabel;
   static JLabel statusLabel;
   static JPanel controlPanel;
   static JButton sub;



   public GUI(){
      prepareGUI();

   }


   public static void prepareGUI(){
      mainFrame = new JFrame("Service 2 - Evaluate Sensor Values");
      mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
      mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
      mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      });    
      headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);        
      statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);    



      controlPanel = new JPanel();
      controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
      mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
      mainFrame.add(statusLabel);

      sub = new JButton("Send Subscribe to Service 1");

      showButtonDemo();

      mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }



   public static void showButtonDemo(){

      headerLabel.setText("Configuration Phase"); 

      headerLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));

      sub.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             Monitor.createWaterSubscriptionResources();
             Monitor.createTemperatureSubscriptionResources();
         }          
      });


      controlPanel.add(sub);


      mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }
}
```

In other class, I will process something, and when the process done, I would like to disable the button in the GUI class, something like:*GUI.sub.setEnabled(false)*. How can I do that?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Is your GUI class still open or not when you call other class?

Comment: hi, my GUI still be opened

Answer (score 1):

In your other class event, you call `Frame.getFrames()` that returns an array of all frames. Then you get your GUI frame and call `GUI.sub.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: hi Sai, could you please explain me a little bit more clear, sorry because I am new in Java ;)

Comment: Can you post your other class action event?

Comment: Let's assume in my second class, I make a simple comparision and if the condition is true, then I disable the button: if(1<2) then I would like to have something like GUI.sub.setEnabled(false)

Answer (score 0):

You should put a getter method for your JButton in the Gui class, Like this:

```
public static JButton getSubButton(){
     return this.sub;
}
```

and to disable the Button from another class you do this:

```
Gui.getsubButton().setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: sub is static field, you can make a static getter, and call it by class name

Comment: hi, when I used GUI gui = new GUI() in my second class, then I will create a new GUI with a disabled button, but I would like to disable the current button in my current GUI, not create a new GUI and disabled it

Comment: when you make a static methode (getter) call it like this : GUI.getSubButton().setEnabled(false); you dont need to create a new Gui

Comment: @samizahwan I didn't see that he declaired his fields as static, you're right  you don't need to instantiate an object to call a static getter you just need the class name, I eddited my answer.